# How would I output the position of NA values in a data frame?

Tags: r

I have the following code...

```
pMiss <- function(x){sum(is.na(x))}
missing_values_data <- apply(csv,1,pMiss)
```

But this just outputs something like...

```
[1]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
[2]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   20    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
[3]    0    0    0    0   10    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
[4]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
[5]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

10 and 20 being the rows that contain NA. Is there a way I could output the index position of these rows in the data frame such as, [3,5] etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the paramater `arr.ind` in the which function to return array indexing. A short example

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(1000), ncol = 10, nrow = 100))
df[1,3] <- NA
df[3,9] <- NA

which(is.na(df), arr.ind = TRUE)

     row col
[1,]   1   3
[2,]   3   9
```

I miss understood the question, if you are interested only in rows then just extract the correct column

```
  > which(is.na(df), arr.ind = TRUE)[ ,1]
[1] 1 3
```

Comment: Thanks @t.f this works well! I have made this an acceptable answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
sapply(df, function(x){which(is.na(x))})

# Data Used: 

df <- data.frame(x1 = c(84.2,105.2,79.2,NA,108.2,79.2,112.2,NA,114.2,92.2),
             x2 = c(138.3,110.3,84.3,45.3,128.3,99.3,NA,124.3,121.3,115.3),
             x3 = as.character(c(138.3,110.3,84.3,45.3,128.3,99.3,100.3,124.3,121.3,115.3)),
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: When I use 'sapply(csv, function(x){which(is.na(x))})' I get the following output on all rows 'integer(0)'.

Comment: You have 0 NA values - in any vector in your csv dataframe.